# Applying Kirchhoff's voltage law to a bipolar junction transistor

Tags: transistors, bjt, common-emitter, kirchhoffs-laws

I am new to the field of electrical engineering. As a part of my curriculum, I am required to study about bipolar junction transistors and their configurations.

**Question:**

In the active *common emitter* configuration of a bipolar junction transistor, the emitter-base junction is forward biased and the collector-emitter junction is "reverse biased". However, as the collector-emitter junction is between two similar terminals (P or N), it does not make any sense to bias them. Thus, we are required to use KVL in order to get effective biasing voltage of the base and the collector.

How can we apply KVL in a CE configuration of a BJT, in order to get the CB voltage?

From [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-apply-KVL-in-collector-to-base-loop-of-a-NPN-BJT-KVL-in-B-E-and-C-E-loop-is-commonly-used!) post on quora, I can see that KVL is applied.

I don't get where exactly the loop was taken (as KVL has to be applied across a loop.) How should one consider the voltage drops of a transistor?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Much confusion over this statement: *However, as collector-emitter junction is between two similar terminals (P or N), it does not make any sense to bias them.*... there is no collector-emitter junction to speak of in a BJT BUT, of course, you do need to bias stuff correctly to get an operational circuit.

Comment: By "Collector Emitter junction", I mean the fact that we "bias" or apply voltage between collector and emitter terminals

Comment: Please provide a neatly labelled circuit diagram with clearly marked components and labelled nodes. And try to mark the loops that you can identify (there will be at least three I think). I think it would be easy to identify the BE loop and the CE loop. From those loops, find VBE and VCE. subtracting them should give you VCB.

Comment: *However, as collector-emitter junction is between two similar terminals (P or N), it does not make any sense to bias them* When I use a BJT as an amplifier, **all** its connections (Base, Collector, Emitter) are biased with a voltage and/or a current. And yes, KVL and KCL still apply, there is no reason why they would not apply.

Comment: To be more specific: What should I subtract from the other? Is it Vbe-Vce or Vce-Vbe?

Comment: Take a look at this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923

Comment: The quora link was working earlier. Now it is dead?

Comment: If \$V_{BE} = V_B - V_E\$ and \$V_{CE} = V_C - V_E\$, then \$V_{CB} = V_{CE} - V_{BE}\$.

Comment: Thank you very much AJN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to apply Thevenin before applying KCL. I suppose that is what you may have missed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xtcs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can now apply KVL:

$$\begin{align*}V_\text{TH}-I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}-I_E\cdot R_\text{E}&=0\:\text{V}\\\\V_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}&=I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}+I_E\cdot R_\text{E}\\\\V_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}&=I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\cdot R_\text{E}\\\\V_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}&=I_B\cdot\left[ R_\text{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_\text{E}\right]\\\\\frac{V_\text{TH}-V_\text{BE}}{R_\text{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_\text{E}}&=I_B\end{align*}$$

And that's all there is to applying KVL to figuring out the DC operating point.

Well, almost.

We failed to take into account the Shockley diode equation as applied to the BJT in active mode. This equation relates the collector current to the base-emitter voltage (either can be determined from the other.) And so, the value you plug in as \$V_\text{BE}\$ is, itself, a variable based upon what you compute as \$I_B\$. While this leads to errors when considering many orders of magnitude difference in collector currents, when considering a much smaller range of such collector currents it is sufficient to simply look at the datasheet to get an eye as to the value to use. Or, failing that, to just guess a reasonable value.

One thing to worry about, when considering specifics about the circuit, is to think about the input signal that you expect to reach the BJT base. Work out the emitter voltage, \$V_E\$, from the above KVL. (Not difficult.) From this, you have the emitter current as \$I_E=\frac{V_E}{R_\text{E}}\$. If the signal magnitude (peak) is expected to be \$v_{_\text{PK}}\$, for example, then work out \$\Delta\:I_{B}=\frac1{\beta+1}\cdot\left[\frac{V_E+v_{_\text{PK}}}{R_\text{E}}-\frac{V_E}{R_\text{E}}\right]=\frac{v_{_\text{PK}}}{\left(\beta+1\right)\,\cdot \,R_\text{E}}\$. Now multiply this by \$R_\text{TH}\$ and find \$\Delta\: V_\text{B}\approx \Delta \:I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}\$.

In general, you want \$\Delta\:V_\text{B}\lt 10\%\cdot V_\text{B}\$. (You already have \$V_\text{B}\$ from KVL and the application of the resulting base current.) If you use base biasing resistors that are too large for the purposes, then this equation will fail.

---

A reasonable design process may use the following design inputs:

- \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$: the intended positive rail voltage.
- \$V_{_\text{EE}}\$: the intended negative rail voltage (may be ground.)
- \$A_v\$: the desired voltage gain.
- \${\small T\! \tiny HD}\$: True harmonic distortion (directly related to the percent-change in voltage gain with respect to the input signal variation.)
- \$R_{_\text{C}}\$: the desired output impedance (another approach would be to specify the input impedance.)
- \$v_{_\text{PP}}\$: the expected AC peak input voltage to the BJT base, after attenuation has been accounted for (you could specify it without knowing the attenuation, too, making this is closer to a *worst-case* spec.)
- \$T_{_\text{MAX}}\$: the maximum intended operating temperature.
- \$T_{_\text{MIN}}\$: the minimum intended operating temperature.

These BJT model details:

- \$\beta\$: a worst case acceptable value for the BJT.
- \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$: the guidance value to use, knowing \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}\$ (use the datasheet or just guess.)
- \$r_e^{\;'}=\frac{V_T}{I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}}\$: the dynamic emitter resistance (AC only, not DC.)

And these physics details:

- \$k\$: Boltzmann's constant.
- \$q\$: magnitude of electron or proton charge.
- \$V_T=\frac{k\,T}{q}\$: thermal voltage (at room temperature this is about \$26\:\text{mV}\$.)

Note: *Nowhere above is the quiescent collector voltage specified.*

Note: *Nowhere above is the quiescent collector current specified.*

The following algorithm will use \$V_{_\text{CC}}=+12\:\text{V}\$, \$V_{_\text{EE}}=-12\:\text{V}\$, \$A_v=-10\$, \${\small T\! \tiny HD}=0.1\;\%\$, \$R_{_\text{C}}=3.3\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$T_{_\text{MAX}}=55^\circ\text{C}\$, \$T_{_\text{MIN}}=-20^\circ\text{C}\$, \$v_{_\text{PP}}=100\:\text{mV}\$, \$\beta=200\$, and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700\:\text{mV}\$.

This means that \$V_{T_{_\text{MAX}}}\approx 28.3\:\text{mV}\$, \$V_{T_{_\text{MIN}}}\approx 21.8\:\text{mV}\$, and \$V_{T_{_\text{RMS}}}\approx 24.8\:\text{mV}\$.

Use the following algorithm:

1. Compute \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=\frac12\cdot A_{v}\cdot\frac{V_{T_{_\text{MAX}}}}{R_{_\text{C}}}\left[1+\sqrt{1+\frac43\frac{v_{_\text{PP}}}{V_{T_{_\text{MIN}}}}\frac1{{T\! \small HD}}}\right]\$. This isn't the exact formula. This version assumes that \$\beta\$ is large enough that \$\frac{\beta+1}{\beta}\approx 1\$ and it ignores other effects such as the base voltage variation that occurs as the signal input varies and the variation of \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ with signal, as well. (The stiffness of the biasing pair can help mitigate some of this.)

   **Note**: \$v_{_\text{PP}}\$ *and* \${\small T\! \tiny HD}\$ *determines your quiescent collector current!*

   (This equation is based on the idea that when considering how voltage gain changes in response to signal this relationship holds: \$\%A_v=\frac{\text{d}\,A_v}{A_v}\approx 3\cdot {\small T\! \tiny HD}\$. You can find this relationship in *"The Art of Electronics"*, Horowitz & Hill, 3rd edition, bottom right corner in the last paragraph of page 94. The derivation of the above equation then follows directly from the basic voltage gain equation for the CE BJT amplifier stage.)

   For example, using the suggested design inputs we get \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}\approx 5.9\:\text{mA}\$. Yes, that's kind of hot. But that's what the THD and signal input requires.
2. Compute \$r_e^{\;'}=\frac{V_{T_{_\text{RMS}}}}{I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}}\approx 4.2\:\Omega\$.
3. Compute \$R_{_\text{E}}=\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{\mid A_v\mid}-r_e^{\;'}=325.8\:\Omega\$. Use the nearby value of \$R_{_\text{E}}=330\:\Omega\$ and adjust \$A_v\$, accordingly, to \$A_v=-\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{E}}+r_e^{\;'}}\approx -9.9\$ (if you like.)
4. Compute \$V_{_\text{E}}=R_{_\text{E}}\cdot I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}+V_{_\text{EE}}\$. In this case, that's \$V_{_\text{E}}\approx -10.05\:\text{V}\$. From this and the above specs, estimate \$V_{_\text{B}}\approx -9.35\:\text{V}\$.
5. The base biasing pair of resistors, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, should have a Thevenin resistance of from 10% to 20% of \$\beta\cdot R_{_\text{E}}\$. So from \$R_{_\text{TH}}\approx 6.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to \$R_{_\text{TH}}\approx 13.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. It's better to use values closer to 10%. But in this example I'll use the less desirable 20% figure.
6. Compute \$V_{_\text{TH}}=V_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot\frac{I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}}{\beta}\approx -8.96\:\text{V}\$.
7. Compute \$R_1=R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{EE}}}{V_{_\text{TH}}-V_{_\text{EE}}}\$ and \$R_2=R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{EE}}}{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{TH}}}\$. Find \$R_1\approx 104\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2\approx 15.1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Perhaps select nearby values of \$R_1=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=15\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

   Recompute \$R_{_\text{TH}}\approx 13.04\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_{_\text{EE}}\cdot R_1+V_{_\text{CC}}\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\approx -8.87\:\text{V}\$. Now find \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=\beta\cdot\frac{V_{_\text{TH}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{EE}}}{R_{_\text{TH}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_{_\text{E}}}\approx 6.1\:\text{mA}\$.

   This is a little hotter than planned. And there may be a problem. So compute the quiescent collector and emitter voltages as \$V_{_\text{C}}=V_{_\text{CC}}-I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}=-8.13\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{_\text{E}}=V_{_\text{EE}}+I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}\cdot\frac{\beta+1}{\beta}=-9.98\:\text{V}\$. The difference is about \$1.85\:\text{V}\$. Given the original desire for a swing of \$\mid A_v\!\mid\cdot\, v_{_\text{PP}}=1\:{\text{V}_\text{PP}}\$ this seems a bit too tight. I'd open it up by lowering \$V_{_\text{B}}\$ by setting \$R_1=91\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=12\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

   Again, recompute \$R_{_\text{TH}}\approx 10.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_{_\text{EE}}\cdot R_1+V_{_\text{CC}}\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\approx -9.2\:\text{V}\$. Now find \$I_{_{\text{C}_Q}}=\beta\cdot\frac{V_{_\text{TH}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{EE}}}{R_{_\text{TH}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_{_\text{E}}}\approx 5.46\:\text{mA}\$. That will definitely open it up enough and it's still relatively close to the original target based upon the required \${\small T\! \tiny HD}\$.

Note that it's straight through until reaching the base biasing pair, when some iterations may be required to complete the design.

That's one process. There are many others.

Answer (score 3):

In general when we analyze the DC condition of the circuit that contains transistors we are trying to distinguish two main loops.

[image]

In input loop (in red):

$$V_{CC} = V_{R_B} + V_{BE} = I_B R_B + V_{BE}$$

And the output loop:

$$V_{CC} = V_{R_C} + V_{CE} = I_CR_C + V_{CE}$$

From the first loop, we can find the base current.  And from the second loop, we can solve for Vce voltage because (\$I_C = \beta *I_B\$)

Comment: What does CC ,BB represents generally in transistors Sir?