# 'Unknown Voltage Requested' error in LTspice

Tags: voltage, current, ltspice, simulation, npn

I made the schematic that is in the first picture and I wanted to plot Vcc vs. Vce but when I tried to plot, it gives an error like in the second picture. How can I fix the error?

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Comment: E is a label for the terminal, but it is not a node.

Comment: Did you re-run the simulation after you assigned the name of the node?

Comment: @G36 Okay it worked but I am not sure it is true or not. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try `V(C,E)`, that means `V(C)-V(E)`. Assuming `C` and `E` are labels (`F4`), not comments (`T`). Try to read the manual (I know, sounds horrible), but the introduction actually shows some of the basics.

Comment: @Mert Sounds like you got it, based upon G36's comment. (You do need to re-run a simulation after you add node names.) Are you good?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Okay, thanks for advice.

Comment: @jonk Yes but I have another problem. Lecturer says that make Vbe=0.7V in the assignment. Is this an initial voltage or should I add a voltage source? (I couldn't work too much transistors therefore sorry for my absence of knowlodge.)

Comment: @Mert Spice will compute the Vbe. The only reason I can think of that the lecturer would tell you to use that value would be if you were being asked to compute the values without using Spice but instead using knowledge about KCL, KVL, and BJT modeling. Is that why?

Comment: @jonk Oh, yes. I have missed  "You need your own calculations" part. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Mert So, have you tried to perform any calculations? Or even develop an equation or two? Any ideas about how to move forward?

Comment: @jonk I don have many idea but I am searching and working on it. I will probably consult you soon.

Comment: @Mert [This may be the closest, recent post of mine similar to your question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452863/38098) [Here is something else related and recent, though there is a small mostly unimportant difference.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/573246/38098)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that the net label is on the pin of the resistor and not connected to a net. The resistor has two pins and if the net label is resting on one of the pins LT spice won't recogize it as connected to a net. (the GUI won't warn you if you have an unconnected net label as shown below with the label d).

I got a similar simulation to work shown below.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you mean that if a label is placed on the pin of an element, instead of the net, itself, it doesn't count (the labels might look crooked, but [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9jI.png))? Or are you referring to the floating `d` node (I don't see anything like that in the OP)?

Comment: The only way for the OP to get the error is if E is not attached to the wire, maybe it's a glitch. What I am saying is if you look at the OP's netlist, odds are E label is not attached for whatever reason. Probably Moving the E label and then moving it back will solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see now, but I think @G36 guessed the problem.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Yes, G36 had nailed it. The OP did properly place the labels. I can tell by the color and orientations. Also, LTspice makes no discernment between lower and upper case. So that also is not the problem.